# Where should I put .pem files in codeigniter to send Apple push notifications?

Tags: php, ios, codeigniter, path, apple-push-notifications

I am developing a Web service in CodeIgniter with a REST_controller library. It is just a controller which manage the requests, I have one request for each method that I use. One of those methods I am trying to use it for send apple Notifications, so I need to use ck.pem file(it is a certificate). I know the problem is that I don't have the good path for the .pem file.

This is the code that I am using. I have the ck.pem file in controllers folder and it does not work.

```
function pushtest_get(){
        $data = array();
    // Put your device token here (without spaces):
        $deviceToken = 'be67171fb22f3ea8fa68c13a9f2ba7229caf3a487aa656b20f769fa2b1fa5b7a';
     // Put your private key's passphrase here:
        $passphrase = 'miguel';
        $message = 'Notification de prueba desde servicio web rest';
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
     // Open a connection to the APNS server
        $fp = stream_socket_client(
            'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
            $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

        if (!$fp)
            exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

        $data['response'] = 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

    // Create the payload body
        $body['aps'] = array(
            'alert' => $message,
            'sound' => 'default'
            );

    // Encode the payload as JSON
        $payload = json_encode($body);

    // Build the binary notification
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

        if (!$result)
           $data['response'] = 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
        else
            $data['response'] = 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

    // Close the connection to the server
        fclose($fp);
        $response->skills = $data;
        $this->response($response, 200);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be solved since it more than a week now, but i want to share since I ran into same problem today.

For CodeIgniter projects, you can keep ck.pem file parallel to application/ directory and then below code will work as it is.

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably put it wherever you want (so long as the webserver has read permissions), just use the full path to the file:

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/var/certs/ck.pem');
```

or

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/var/www/codeigniter/application/controllers/ck.pem');
```

I wouldn't keep it in the controllers folder, though. It be confusing for others who may work on the project and might make it hard for you to find in the future.

I'd make a certificate directory somewhere and store it there.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should keep in a folder say `certs` in the root of your project say:

```
/certs/ck.pem
```

And then:

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', './certs/ck.pem');
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where you have pem files . But good practice is to have it in root directory.

Check for correct environment of sandbox like for development port is 2195 and for production it is 2196.

Also check for correct pem files that you generated for development and production and make sure you pass correct passpharase value .

Hope it helps you :)